# Upload files to Cloud Storage as a Functions deployment step

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage

When I build and deploy my functions, I want to run a script that also uploads a series of files to Cloud Storage. These files don't fit in the 100 MB limit for functions, so the functions will access them when needed.

As far as I understand, the dynamics are fairly simple:

1. Write said script with logic to detect which files need to be uploaded.
2. Within it, initialize Firebase using the `firebase-admin` SDK and a service account key from GCP.
3. Run this script as part of the NPM script that deploys.

The complication comes when I try to adapt this process to nicely handle my 3 environments (modeled in 3 projects) and the emulator.

For instance:

- How should I graciously detect which project to connect to within the deployment process? I tried using `firebase-tools` to at least get the current project as a module instead of a CLI tool, but it is not documented at all (or typed, for that matter).
- How can I connect this step to the steps the emulator follows on every internal deployment to ensure those files are also loaded in the emulated storage?

By going outside of the standard environment and uploading stuff from my local environment I seem to lose quite a bit of the internal set up Firebase provides through its CLI, but I wonder if there's anything I might be missing here.

**Tl;dr**: I want to upload files to Storage during Functions deployment, seamlessly detecting which environment the deployment is targeting.

Comment: Cloud Firestore and Cloud Storage are two separate products. Please edit your question so that you identify which of the two you actually want. Based on what you describe, you want Cloud Storage.

Comment: Even though Firebase's Storage is a wrapper for Cloud Storage, I believe it's still relevant in this case that the solution must consider the top-level abstraction, as it is the one I’m interacting with.

Comment: As you can also see by Puf's updates to your question, Firestore is not shorthand for the Firebase Cloud Storage SDK. "Cloud Firestore" is a NoSQL database and Cloud Storage is a blob storage service. I'll come back to this later and see if the current deploy target is exposed as an environment variable (I know the resource directory is) during deployment. For now you want to look up the docs for the "predeploy" and "postdeploy" hooks.

Comment: My sincere apologies gentlemen, I was coming out of an all-nighter. Thanks for the pointer on pre/post-deploy hooks.